# Best way to store a large python dictionary in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script (script 1) which generate a large python dictionary. This dictionary has to be read by an another script (script 2). 
Could any one suggest me the best way to write the python dictionary generated by script 1 and to be read by script 2.
In past I have used cPickle to write and read such large dictionaries.
Is there a beter way to do this?

Comment: Another name for a "large dictionary" is a "database".

Answer (score 8):

[`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) will give you access to each item separately, instead of requiring you to serialize and deserialize the entire dictionary each time.

Comment: shelve is great so long as all the keys are strings

Comment: @John La Rooy. What if the keys are strings?

Answer (score 4):

If you want your dictionary to be readable by different types of scripts (i.e. not just Python), [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) is a good option as well.

It's not as fast as `shelve`, but it's easy to use and quite readable to the human eye.

---

```py
import json
with open("/tmp/test.json", "w") as out_handle:
    json.dump(my_dict, out_handle)  # save dictionary

with open("/tmp/test.json", "r") as in_handle:
    my_dict = json.load(in_handle)  # load dictionary
```

Comment: With really large dictionaries, json can run out of memory.